# SMS in Android with Cordova

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I've using Cordova 2.9.0 to send sms in Android. Can i send sms with multiple body?. by default we can do Programatically like this.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
     $("#btnDefaultSMS").click(function(){

            var number = $("#numberTxt").val();
            var message = $("#messageTxt").val();
            SmsPlugin.prototype.send(number, message, '',
                function () { 
                   alert('Message sent successfully');  
                },
                function (e) {
                    alert('Message Failed:' + e);
                }
            );               
         }); 
     });

  </script>
```

and i want to make diff with create more variable

$(document).ready(function() {

```
     $("#btnDefaultSMS").click(function(){

            var number = $("#numberTxt").val();
            var messageOne = $("#MessageOne").val();
            var messageTwo = $("#MessageTwo").val();
            var messageThree = $("#MessageThree ").val();
            var messageFour = $("#MessageFour").val();
            SmsPlugin.prototype.send(number, messageOne, messageTwo, messageThree, messageFour, '',
                function () { 
                   alert('Message sent successfully');  
                },
                function (e) {
                    alert('Message Failed:' + e);
                }
            );               
         }); 
     });

  </script>
```

and HTML Tag like this, and so on.

textarea name="message" id="messageTxt" placeholder="Enter message" data-mini="false"

But, unfortunately. only first textarea could sent, and second, third, and four textarea can't.. any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've some way out to make this happen..
in JavaScript, we can concat all available variable has instantiate, for example: 

var number = $("#numberTxt").val() + "" + 
             $("#MessageOne").val(); + "" + 
             $("#MessageTwo").val(); + "" +
             $("#MessageThree ").val(); + "" +
             $("#MessageFour").val();

This explanation coming from my friend "@ibraheemOM". and "@javatechig" thanks for helping me.